# Python GraphQL Client - Unexpected punctuator when passing variables

Tags: python, graphql, ethereum, thegraph

Code:

```
contract="0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"

query = """
($contract: Int!) {
 token(id:$contract){
   name
   symbol
   decimals
   derivedETH
   tradeVolumeUSD
   totalLiquidity
 }
}
"""

variables = {
    "contract": contract
}

data = client.execute(query=query, variables=variables)
```

Error:

```
{'errors': [{'locations': [{'column': 1, 'line': 2}], 'message': 'Unexpected `([Punctuator]`\nExpected `{`, `query`, `mutation`, `subscription` or `fragment`'}]}
```

I've tried reformatting a number of ways and I cannot get this error to go away! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GraphQL query must start with a `query`:

```
query($someVar: String!) {
  someQuery(someArg: $someVar) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does my query work exactly as above without variables? If I simply remove

"($contract: Int!)" 

and change

 token(id:$contract) to

 token(id: "0x00...etc")

everything runs fine

Comment: This did fix it! I'm just curious why it works without "query" if I do not include variables.

Comment: @Marcus Without variables, most GQL clients send the `query` prefix implicitly

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!